# How to install latest ruby version in Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3b+, ruby

I have a `raspberry pi` which has the latest raspbian os. If I install `ruby` in it using `sudo apt-get install ruby-full`, `ruby 2.5` version is installed. I have another `raspberry pi` which is running the older raspbian os. If I run the same above command in it, `ruby 2.3` version is installed.

How can I update the `2.3` version to `2.5`. Please help. Thanks

Here is the response of `cat /etc/os-release` of my older raspbian os

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: if by "older raspbian" you mean something before `buster`, the solution is to install buster

Comment: @JaromandaX I am using `stretch`. I have updated the question

Comment: the solution is to install buster

Comment: You could also install any version of ruby you like through either [RVM](http://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

Comment: @Dan in 1`rbenv`, especially on SBC operating systems, the most recent version available is well behind those you can compile, many of which struggle to get completed.  `OpenSSL` is one such reason.